# SuperLU Distributed - Slow

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, solver

I'm here again for SuperLU_distributed solver issue.

Since I've noticed that parallel version of my algorith was running very slow, I tried to simply run test programs (pddrive) saved in my build/EXAMPLE folder, compiled by SuperLU during its installation.

I've noticed that, while running with mpirun -n 1 gives good time in solving, if I increase number of processes time become very slow (more I increase processes more it slows down).

It looks strange since it is the test program of SuperLU with no modifications.

Have anyone had a similar trouble?

thank you
Simone

Comment: Have you resolved this problem?